# jQuery Forms Authentication with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Is it possible to use a jQuery ajax call to perform Forms Authentication with ASP.NET MVC? I've been unable to find any such examples.

More specifically, how do I set the auth cookie on the page (without a redirect) so I can make successive authenticated ajax requests?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Just submit the login-form using the method [described here by mike bosch](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-mvc-submitting-ajax-form-with-jquery.aspx) and return a json datastructure with the returnUrl if any.

I have created a lightweight LoginResultDTO class that i return as json:

```
public class LoginResultDTO
{
  public bool Success {get;set;}
  public string Message {get;set;}
  public string ReturnUrl {get;set;}
}
```

Here's a script block from my LogOn view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var form = $($("form")[0]);
            form.submit(function() {
                var data = form.serialize();
                $.post(form.attr("action"), data, function(result, status) {
                    if (result.Success && result.ReturnUrl) {
                            location.href = result.ReturnUrl;
                    } else {
                        alert(result.Message);
                    }
                }, "json");
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

This will ajax wrap the logon form. Note that this is the simplest implementation of the javascript code possible but it's a place to start.

Then I have modified my LogOn action in the AccountController and in the relevant places put something like this:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
  return Json(new LoginResultDTO{Success=true,Message="Successfully logged in"});
}else
{
  return View();
}
```

So this is an ultralight but rather complete version of how jquery authentication could be done in asp.net mvc.

Comment: If I'm not doing a redirect, how would the auth cookie get set on that page?

Comment: Things are good when that ajax post returns with a success result. But you will almost always redirect after a successfull login. In the ajax scenario by assigning the url to the `location.href` property in javascript.

Comment: I just fired up firebug to see what's going on. When you hit the LogOn action with ajax and your login is successful, there's a set-cookie entry in the response header with the auth cookie. That's why it works.

Comment: but this doesn't work with $.getJSON ... which is the only way to make cross site authentication work ... how do you handle this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/). It can use any client-side validation library but uses [jQuery Valiation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) by default.