# Laravel 4 Check if logged in (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Evening,

I have one (maybe simple question), which I can't figure out how to do on my own. I'm using Laravel Framework version 4.

How can I check if a user is logged in within javascript? I want the menu bar to fadeout when a user scrolls 100px down, but if the user is logged in then I want it to fadeout when the user scrolls 150px down..

This is how the javascript looks like by now:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var yPos = ( $(window).scrollTop() );
    if(yPos > 100) { // show sticky menu after screen has scrolled down 200px from the top
        $("#fixed_header").fadeIn(100);
        $("#fixed_header_konto").fadeIn(100);
        $("#header").fadeOut(100);
        $("#header_konto").fadeOut(100);
    } else {
        $("#fixed_header").fadeOut(100);
        $("#fixed_header_konto").fadeOut(100);
        $("#header").fadeIn(100);
        $("#header_konto").fadeIn(100);
    }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450107/1438393).

Comment: Mhm, can't seem to find a way through that answer... Sorry

Comment: You'll have to check server-side to know if a user is *actually* logged in. There's no way to do that with JavaScript alone. The above answer shows how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it in your view by using the following code:

```
@if(Auth::check())

  <script>{{ 'var logged = true;' }}</script>

@endif
```

That way you can check the `logged` value via javascript to check if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `view composer` to dump the logged in user data (you may just pass a flag either) directly to the `JavasScript` using something like this:

```
View::composer('layouts.master', function($view) {
    $user = null;
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
    }
    $view->with('authUser', $user);
});
```

Your master layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>var userObj = {{ $authUser or 'undefined' }}</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, you may able to check if the user is logged in or not by using something like this:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    if(userObj) console.log(userObj);
  });
</script>
```

This is from my last article written on march `6th March, 2014` on [Heera.IT](http://heera.it), check the article for more detailed explanation. Also, you may don't need to dump the whole `user object` but it's fine.