# Laravel: How to check whether a user logged in or not by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel

Although I know about the `authentication` check via `laravel`, I want to know how to check via `jQuery`.

Actually, I want to change my `CSS` If user logged in.
By default:

```
body{
    background: url('image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

If user logged in, my `CSS` should be updated like:

```
body{
    /*Nothing*/
}
```

I've tried something in my `js` file:

```
var loggedIn={!! json_encode(Auth::check()) !!};
if(loggedIn)
    alert('Logged In as user!');
```

But the above code didn't work for me.
I need help. If my purpose can be done in any alternative way, you may share.

Thanks

Comment: This help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273830/laravel-4-check-if-logged-in-javascript

Comment: just remove the json_encode

Comment: Not working @Omi

Comment: check the console for errors

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
var loggedIn = {{ auth()->check() ? 'true' : 'false' }};
if (loggedIn)
    alert('Logged In as user!');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you place anywhere in you template a script block like this:

```
    <script>
        var AuthUser = "{{{ (Auth::user()) ? Auth::user() : null }}}";
    </script>
```

Then you can access AuthUser variable in javascript

Comment: This won't work in js... It's going to read var AuthUser as a string.  The output of a console.log would be {{{ (Auth::user()) ? Auth::user() : null }}}

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already uses a `window.Laravel` definition, so let's just extend that in the head of the master template:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {
        csrfToken: '{{csrf_token()}}',
        auth: {
            user: auth()->user()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And how can I get user info in script ?

Comment: @SMIftakhairul `window.Laravel.auth.user`

Comment: ...or just Laravel.auth.user